# Looking for a simple forum script

Tags: php, mysql, forum, integration

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [What Forum Software should I use?](https://webmasters.stackexchange.com/questions/25771/what-forum-software-should-i-use)

I have a working website and I need to integrate a forum into it. The problem is, I need the forum script to use usernames and passwords from a mysql table that is already created. This is why I need a forum that supports translations and has a simple code I can adjust to my databse.
Any ideas on such forum scripts?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There's [Vanilla](http://vanillaforums.org/) and [bbPress](http://bbpress.org/). They're both relatively simple and have good communities.

Answer (score 0):

phpBB

THE #1 FREE, OPEN SOURCE BULLETIN BOARD SOFTWARE.
phpBB is a free flat-forum bulletin board software solution that can be used to stay in touch with a group of people or can power your entire website.
No other bulletin board software offers a greater complement of features, while maintaining efficiency and ease of use. Best of all, phpBB is completely free.

Comment: phpBB is a good solution (if you're diligent about keeping it up to date), but try not to submit answers that read like marketing copy.

Answer (score 0):

I personally like forum content management systems by phpBB and vBulletin.

Comment: Please don't consider as marketing. This is just for a suggestion.

Answer (score 0):

I personally use Vanilla as well, and used to use phpBB before. Both are easy to use and highly customizable if you read the documentation.

Also, [Wikipedia's comparison of PHP forum software](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Comparison_of_Internet_forum_software_%28PHP%29) has a few more suggestions and lists some common functionality.